# (SQL) Creating an uncorrelated query

Tags: sql

I had to write an SQL-Query for a given Database (it's huge, I won't be able to post it here, but its about artists with albums and release dates, genres etc.).

The Task was to find all artists involved in albums which contains the word "drop". I had to write an correlated and an uncorrelated query. I got the correlated:

```
SELECT artist
FROM CDDB.ARTISTS ar
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT album
     FROM CDDB.ALBUMS al
     INNER JOIN CDDB.ARTIST2ALBUM aa ON al.albumid = aa.albumid
     WHERE ar.artistid = aa.artistid
       AND album LIKE '\%drop\%');
```

Now I have to make that uncorrelated, but I don't know how. Is it possible that one can help me without the given tables etc.?

Comment: `Is it possible that one can help me without the given tables etc.?` Maybe, but it's far more likely that someone could help you with the table structure and sample data

Comment: nonetheless its predictible :)

Answer (score 0):

Uncorrelated subqueries are subqueries that can be run independently from the outer query.

Generally speaking, `EXISTS` is correlated, `IN` is uncorrelated.

If you change your query to something like:

```
SELECT artist
FROM CDDB.ARTISTS ar
INNER JOIN CDDB.ARTIST2ALBUM aa ON ar.artistid = aa.artistid
WHERE album in
    (SELECT album
     FROM CDDB.ALBUMS 
     WHERE album LIKE '%drop%');
```

It is now uncorrelated.